# How to use Server.htmlEncode / Server.htmlDecode without compromising security?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-encode

**QUESTION**

How to submit html code to a textbox and output as text without compromising security?

This is what I'm currently trying:

**DATA GOES IN (SUBMITTED INTO TEXTBOX)**

```
Dim txtInput As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Me.txtInput.Text)
```

**DATA COMES OUT (READ AS TEXT ON PAGE)**

```
txtOutput.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(MyText)
```

Desired output is for the format to be the same as initially entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should HtmlEncode text you are setting in a textbox:

`txtOutput.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(MyText)`

And HtmlDecode text you are getting from a textbox:

`MyText = Server.HtmlDecode(txtOutput.Text)`

If you're storing the data in sql then I recommend using [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) as well.  It handles most security concerns, such as SQL injection, for you.

Comment: This seems like the opposite of what should be done. Shouldn't you encode anything that you send to the output to prevent scripts from executing?

Comment: It should be the opposite.

Comment: it was def reversed. woops